# Get data from MySQL and shows as clickable URL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying Get data from MySQL and shows as clickable URL but not works on my side.

```
<span>Company URL: </span> <?php echo $row1['url']; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do like that

```
<span>Company URL: </span> 
<a href="<?php echo $row1['url']; ?>"> 
   <?php echo $row1['url']; ?> 
</a>
```

Comment: it's working but how web address without showing as Link.

Comment: `<a target = '_blank' href="<?php echo $row1['url']; ?>"> 
   <?php echo $row1['url']; ?> 
</a>`
with New tap code.